# What is meant by "natural unsigned int"

Tags: cil

In the documentation for `ldlen` and `localloc` the size type is described as "natural unsigned int". Although I have an idea what is meant (on x64: 64 bit unsigned on x86: 32 bit unsigned) I haven't found any documentation for it.

So is there an "official" documentation about the "natural unsigned int"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term `natural` refers, as you thought, to what is native on the hardware. Although it's not specified explicitly in a glossary, you can make it out from other uses of the word `natural` in the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf):

> The native size types (native int, 
>   native unsigned int, and &) are always naturally aligned (4 bytes or 8 bytes, depending on the 
>   architecture).

or

> autochar indicates a 
>   platform-specific representation that is “natural” for the underlying platform